# Issues with Infinite Double Slope in Java

Tags: java, computational-geometry, lines, infinity

I am working on a computational geometry projects which contains classes for Point, Line, Triangle, etc.  I store lines as a yint and a slope, however this is giving me issues with vertical lines, as shown in the issue below.  I have to maintain the usage of slopes generally, however I could do a conversion to degrees if you feel this is appropriate for the situation.

Below is a method to get an array of all of the altitudes of a triangle, implemented in the triangle class.  It does not work.  I am pretty sure it is due to infinite slopes, but not entirely.  Any ideas?

```
//sides is an array of LineSegs {AB, BC, CA}
public Line[] getLineAltitudes() {
    Line[] returner = new Line[3];

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        //decides which point is opposite to lineseg
        int pointgot = 0;
        if (i == 0) pointgot = 2;
        else if (i == 1) pointgot = 0;
        else pointgot = 1;

        //gets the perpendicular to a side          
        Double newSlope = (double)1/sides[i].getSlope();
        System.out.println(newSlope);

        if (newSlope.isInfinite()) newSlope = (double) 0;

        //constructs a line using the (working) constructor Line(point on line, slope)
        returner[i] = new Line(getPoints()[pointgot],newSlope);
    }

    return returner;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "does not work" means in your question; but if I had to model lines in 2D Euclidean space, I'd use the form `ax + by + c = 0`, and have a class that stores `a`, `b` and `c`.  Of course, two lines are treated as equal if the ratios of `a` to `b` to `c` are the same.

Comment: In this case, does not work means that it returns a null line when the line is either vertical or horizontal.  And no, sadly I cannot modify how the line classes work.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're looking to find the slope of a line that's perpendicular to another, you need to divide `-1` by the other line's slope, not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

To handle vertical slopes, using angular measurements instead of slope would allow you to do so without this issue.  Consider using [java.lang.Math.atan2(double y, double x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) to get a vertical angle when there is a zero change in the x value.